# Has anyone seen timing/synchronization problems with SPO REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online

We've got a strange situation with our SharePoint Online project.  We're using the API to create folders, add permissions and upload a stock set of files for a directory we're giving to clients to use.  When creating the folder structure, we're seeing strange errors, like 404 errors popping up when we try and access something after creating it.  Not always, but sometimes.

Is there some additional status that we need to check after creating or modifying an SPO resource?

Answer (score 0):

For creating folder using Rest, you can check the new created folder relative url in Success Handler to make sure the new folder already created like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        bindButtonClick();
        });
        function bindButtonClick() {
            $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
                createFolder();
            });
        }

        function createFolder() 
        {
            var folderName = $("#txtFolderName").val();
            var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/folders";
            $.ajax({
            url: fullUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' },
            'ServerRelativeUrl': 'Shared Documents/' + folderName
            }),
            headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "aysnc": false
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.d.ServerRelativeUrl)
                {
                    console.log("Successfully creating folder")
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }


    </script>

    <div>
    <strong>Enter Folder Name:</strong>
    <input type="text" id="txtFolderName" />
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div id="divResults"></div>
```